# Prolog - Nth Permutation of 3 elements

Tags: prolog, permutation

I would like to get the nth permutation of 3 elements.
Eg.

List = [1,2,3]
n = 5

Output
[1,2,3,1,2]
[1,2,3,2,1]
...

I don't want any continuous same element such as
[1,1,1,1,1]
[1,2,3,3,2]
...

I have try few which can get the full permutation, couldn't figure how to get what I needed.

```
varia_repp(N,RVaria):-varia_rep(N,[1,2,3],RVaria).

varia_rep(0,_,[]).
varia_rep(N,[H|L],RVaria):-N>0,N1 is N-1,delete(H,[H|L],_),varia_rep(N1,[H|L],RVaria).
```

or

```
perm(List,[H|Perm]):-delete(H,List,Rest),perm(Rest,Perm).
perm([],[]).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this (note that the permutations are in lexicographical order) is to explicitly state that two consecutive elements cannot be the same:

```
perm(1, Input, [Last]) :-
    member(Last, Input).
perm(N, Input, [First,Second|Perm]) :-
    N > 1, N0 is N-1,
    member(First, Input),
    dif(First, Second),
    perm(N0, Input, [Second|Perm]).

?- perm(3,[a,b,c],R).
R = [a, b, a] ;
R = [a, b, c] ;
R = [a, c, a] ;
R = [a, c, b] ;
R = [b, a, b] ;
R = [b, a, c] ;
R = [b, c, a] ;
R = [b, c, b] ;
R = [c, a, b] ;
R = [c, a, c] ;
R = [c, b, a] ;
R = [c, b, c] ;
false.
```

You have tagged the question with swi-prolog. It has a predicate [dif/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=dif/2), like other major Prolog implementations. You can also find quite a few interesting discussions on StackOverflow about dif/2, with pros and cons. To summarize, it poses a constraint that its two arguments cannot unify. It can be used for non-instantiated variables and in this case prevents a lot of unnecessary backtracking without any explicit cuts or extra arguments.

Also, delete/3 is deprecated in favor of select/3. Here however you only need member/2 (as you want to reuse elements).

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, while dif/2 keeps things shorter, it might be a bit confusing. Here is an almost identical, slightly more verbose version without dif/2 (which happens to also work much faster for larger N's).

```
p(N, Input, [First|Rest]) :-
    N >= 1, N0 is N-1,
    member(First, Input),
    p(N0, Input, First, Rest).

p(0, _, _, []).
p(N, Input, Prev, [This|Rest]) :-
    N > 0, N0 is N-1,
    member(This, Input), This \= Prev,
    p(N0, Input, This, Rest).
```

Comment: nice code (+1), but not easy to understand (as often the case where delayed goals are involved). I assume you tested the sample case from the OP.

Comment: thanks it works, but I don't understand bout the dif(First, Second). This is not the processing of prolog, so where is this diff and what does it do? Do you mind explain details to me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @NinjoeQuah: dif/2 can deal with yet-to-be-instanced variables (`Second` here). There are chances that instead of perm/2 we could write a simpler `..., perm(N0, Input, [Second|Perm]), Second =\= First.`

Comment: @CapelliC Yes, I tested the sample code. As the solutions are in lexicographical order, those come far down so I didn't feel like clicking through.... As for ease of understanding, it is a matter of taste and experience I guess. I don't have that much experience and my taste is always towards the most obvious.

Comment: is it possible to make it the last element and first element diff too? such as exclude [a,b,a], [b,a,b],[c,a,c]...?

Comment: @NinjoeQuah I guess you can, but what you might consider is first coming up with a proper definition of your problem. I can still only guess what is the actual goal you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, beware to efficiency: if your lists are large, dif/2 must not be misused.

Comment: ok. What Im trying to do is to schedule nth subject into 3 timeslot. Foreach subject, it cannot be conflict with its predecessor and successor.  Thats why I thought that permutation with repeated elements will be the best, but than I couldn't exclude what I stated.

Comment: @CapelliC Do you mean large lists in the arguments to dif/2?

Comment: @Boris: as I understand your code, it build a dif constraint for each element selected. Isn't it ? Then it going to apply N! times...

Comment: I suggest you describe in the question (or in a new question) your actual problem with a complete problem description. I think your problem is not the Prolog code, but the program logic and the algorithm it translates to.

Comment: @CapelliC Well, it only poses the constraint that two consecutive elements cannot be the same. It only prevents member/2 from choosing the same element in two consecutive calls of perm/3 (and this can happen once or not at all). It seems to me that the number of possible solutions is the actual problem with bigger input lists (or bigger N). Am I missing something?

Comment: ok for this perm(1, Input, [Last]) :-
    member(Last, Input).   
How do I get the first element from the Last? If I'm able to get the first, then I just need to check Last =\= First.

Comment: @NinjoeQuah Before going into the recursive predicate, pick out the first element. Then pass it down the recursive call in an extra argument.

Comment: Is `[b,c,b]` an allowed solution? In this case, should permutations not contain all of the original elements?

Comment: Solutions provided by @Boris allowed [b,c,b], but I had make changes which don't allowed [b,c,b]

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your sample, you don't need the nth permutation of K elements (K = 3 in your sample), but the permutation of N elements, where the list of N is built flood filling with elements from the template list, then filtered to exclude contiguous equal elements:

```
varia_rep(N, L, P) :-
  build_rep(L, N, P0),
  permutation(P0, P),
  \+ append(_, [X,X|_], P).

build_rep(L, N, P0) :-
  length(L, K),
  findall(X, (between(1, N, I), J is ((I-1) mod K) + 1, nth1(J, L, X)), P0).
```

test:

```
?- build_rep([1,2,3],5,P).
P = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2].

?- varia_rep(5,[1,2,3],P).
P = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2] ;
P = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1] ;
P = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2] ...
```