# All possible combinations of a given string

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

I need to find all possible combinations of a given string, from a minimum length to a maximum length.

```
interface allCombos(string: String, min: Number, max:Number): Array {}
```

So if my input string is `‘abcde’`, and my minimum length is 3, I want the result to be:

For length 3:

```
[‘abc’, ‘abd’, ‘abe’, ‘acd’, ..., ‘bcd’, ‘bce’, ..., ‘eda’, ...]
```

Concatenated with length 4:

```
[‘abcd’, ‘abdc’, ‘acdb’, ‘acbd’, …etc]
```

Concatenated with all possible combinations with length up to the max parameter. Which shouldn't be higher than the input word length.

I started thinking that all possible combinations would be `∑(3! + 4! + … + n!)`. But then I saw I'm wrong because for every length subset, there are many combinations for the whole world (for example 3-length combinations of a 6 letter string).

Can the community help me with this problem?

The solution can either be in `JavaScript`, `Python` or even pseudo code.

**Edit**

For knowledge's sake. Could anyone answer me, the formula that describes the result size in this case? I know its not  `∑(3! + 4! + … + n!)`.

Comment: If the string has a duplicate letter, should each letter be considered independently? (If you had "bb", would you end up with "b" or "bb" or ["bb", "bb"]?)

Comment: Is the Question relevant to python or JavaScript?

Comment: Well guest271314 i think so because i'd rather have a coded solution in those languages

Comment: John Doe yes, even if there are duplicates i want to calculate them

Comment: What do you mean by "those languages"? The question subject matter is permutations, and not combinatorics, yes?

Comment: guest271314 See well if im wrong in some point just correct me because i am a little bit rusty on the theory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for this:

```
from itertools import combinations

["".join(li) for li in combinations('abcde', 3)]
```

This will give

```
['abc', 'abd', 'abe', 'acd', 'ace', 'ade', 'bcd', 'bce', 'bde', 'cde']
```

Brief explanation:

```
list(combinations('abcde', 3))
```

will give

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('a', 'b', 'd'),
 ('a', 'b', 'e'),
 ('a', 'c', 'd'),
 ('a', 'c', 'e'),
 ('a', 'd', 'e'),
 ('b', 'c', 'd'),
 ('b', 'c', 'e'),
 ('b', 'd', 'e'),
 ('c', 'd', 'e')]
```

so all combinations of three of your letters. You can join the individual tuples then in a list comprehension.

You can then of course easily put this in a loop if you like:

```
min_length = 3
max_length = 5

res = {str(i): ["".join(li) for li in combinations('abcde', i)] for i in range(min_length, max_length + 1)}
```

This gives

```
{'3': ['abc', 'abd', 'abe', 'acd', 'ace', 'ade', 'bcd', 'bce', 'bde', 'cde'],
 '4': ['abcd', 'abce', 'abde', 'acde', 'bcde'],
 '5': ['abcde']}
```

If you want to have it in a single list:

```
import numpy as np
final_list = np.concatenate(res.values())
```

which yields

```
array(['abc', 'abd', 'abe', 'acd', 'ace', 'ade', 'bcd', 'bce', 'bde',
       'cde', 'abcde', 'abcd', 'abce', 'abde', 'acde', 'bcde'],
      dtype='|S5')
```

Comment: What happens when I want to concatenate combinations of 3, with comibations of 4 and 5? this is the part that im missing

Comment: @frankies Not sure if I understand what you mean by "concatenate combinations of 3, with comibations of 4 and 5". Could you elaborate on your expected outcome?

Comment: As said in my question. My input string is 'permu'. I want an array of length 3 with the permutations of all letters, plus an array of 4, plus an array of 5.

Comment: See. thats not what im expecting, because for Length 5, i want all possible combinations with all letters! 'abcde', 'cdbae', 'eabcd', ....

Comment: @frankies: Then use `itertools.permutations` instead of `itertools.combinations`; rest of the code is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I am happy to introduce you to the wonderful python standard library [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html)! You will want to use the combinations function. What is awesome about this library is that it solves almost all combinatoric loop problems.

```
 import itertools

 min_length = 2
 max_length = 5

 s = 'ABCDEF'
 for i in range(min_length, max_length):
     print('length', i, 'cominations')
     print([_ for _ in itertools.combinations(s, i)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Others showed you some nice options for combinations/permutations, but I think your full expected output is something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations

def allCombos(str, min_length, max_length):
    str_combinations = []
    for length in range(min_length, max_length):
        combinations = [''.join(c) for c in combinations(str, length)]
        str_combinations.append(combinations)
    return str_combinations
```

Comment: yes! i think you are close but:  ```UnboundLocalError: local variable 'combinations' referenced before assignment```

Comment: Oops, I imported one option and used the other, haha. I was dashing it off quickly as I left work. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

> [Edit]: For knowledge's sake. Could anyone answer me, the formula that
>   describes the result size in this case? I know its not ∑(3! + 4! + … +
>   n!).

Below find three mathematical approaches which provide the same ultimate result using JavaScript. For further descriptions of the procedure see

- [Permutation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Permutation.html)
- [Permutations without recursive function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013675/permutations-without-recursive-function-call)
- [How to improve efficiency of algorithm which generates next lexicographic permutation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290467/how-to-improve-efficiency-of-algorithm-which-generates-next-lexicographic-permut)

further items of interest within the subject matter

- [There are apparently  3072  ways to draw this flower. But why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736483/there-are-apparently-3072-ways-to-draw-this-flower-but-why)
- [What is the shortest string that contains all permutations of an alphabet?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/what-is-the-shortest-string-that-contains-all-permutations-of-an-alphabet)

```js
const n = 4;

{
  console.log("multiplication in loop:\n");
  let l = 1,
    k;

  for (let i = k = n; l < i; k *= l++);

  console.log({
    [`${n}!`]: k
  });
}

{
  console.log("single multiplication 4 * 3 * 2 * 1:\n");
  console.log({
    [`${n}!`]: 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
  });

}

{
  console.log("multiplication in steps:\n");
  
  let curr = n;
  
  let acc = {};
  
  acc[`${curr} * ${curr - 1}`] = curr * --curr;
  
  console.log(acc);
  
  acc[`${Object.keys(acc).pop()} * ${--curr}`] = curr * +acc[Object.keys(acc).pop()];
  
  console.log(acc);
  
  acc[`${Object.keys(acc).pop()} * ${--curr}`] = curr * +acc[Object.keys(acc).pop()];
  
  console.log(acc);

}
```